# sleep() mutes eventSource [php]

Tags: php, server, server-sent-events

trying to implement an eventSource on server-side php like this:

```
header("Content-Type: text/event-stream");
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
Date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Tehran');

$path = '/home/bluhbluh/public_html/sign_in/folderName/';


while(true){

    echo "retry: 1000" . PHP_EOL; // retry interval
    ob_end_flush();

    $files = array_diff(
        scandir('folderName/'),
        ['.','..']
    );

    $phoneNumbers = array();
    $p = '';
    foreach($files as $file){
        // read file
        $p = preg_replace(
            '/[^0-9]/', 
            '', 
            file_get_contents($path . $file, FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH)
        );

        $phoneNumbers[] = $p;

        // remove file
        unlink($path . $file);


       // send event
        // echo 'event: send' . PHP_EOL; // event type
        echo 'data: ' . $p, "\n\n"; // phoneNumber
        while (ob_get_level() > 0) {
            ob_end_flush();
        }
        flush();

    }


      if ( connection_status() != CONNECTION_NORMAL or connection_aborted() ) break;

      sleep(5);
}

if( ob_get_level() > 0 ) {
    while (ob_get_level() > 0)
        ob_flush();
    ob_end_clean();
}
```

but eventSource is not sending the events!

if I remove the sleep() function , it works just fine.

**what is causing the problem here ?**

I said "**Mutes**" because it does the job(scans the directory and all ...) , except the sending event part.

**what makes it even weirder is that this works fine when run locally but not on remote shared host**

-=-=-=-=-
[update]

server it seems is buffering the output.
disabling the buffering solves the issue.

- it worked localy because remote server was using mod_fastcgi and default buffering size is not 0 (like my xampp apache local server's is)

Comment: doesnt it run infinite ? do you start an `ob_start();`

Comment: @Dilek yes it runs indefinitely , wasn't in the code , but tested it now and doesn't make any difference it seems , should it be outside the while loop ?

Comment: yes, I didnt see a working `sleep();` function in loop, because while loop is repeating `sleep();` so its driving query to infinite. there should be some other methods to make it work in loop, But I didnt see any yet. what is you change this `while(true){` TO `if($value === true){` ?

Comment: @Dilek well everyOne keeps recommending it , like [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events)

Comment: @Dilek did a recursive method instead of while loop , made no difference.  
is that what you meant by `if($value === true)` ?

Comment: Well even if it work its not quarante it will return certain time, I would use `DelayQueue` instead sleep. it will  **let it stay as its**, tought its just a validating.

Comment: @Dilek DelayQueue seems to be a third-party library. might take a little time to install it on a shared host

Comment: Nvm just use `sleep();` or `usleep();`

Comment: @Dilek the problem with sleep() is explained in the question